# Cakephp Validation on API input data

Tags: api, validation, rest, cakephp, model

I have an API that receives data in JSON, XML and FORM data. The API needs to do a bit of validation that depending on the data provided, depends on the data to be validated. I have a "sendmode" field that is required for each API call. If the sendmode = 1 then mobile,firstname and lastname are required fields, however, if sendmode is 2 then group is a required field.

My question is, how can I validate my data in my model according to data provided in the API call without having to do a bunch of If statements at the beginning of my controller?

Thanks

```
public function api_send() {
    //Get Params
    $data = $this->request->input('json_decode', TRUE);

    //validate here -> first required
    $data['sendmode'] //need to validate
    $data['subject']   //need to validate
    $data['message']  //need to validate

   if($validate == false){
      return;
      break;
   } 

   switch($data['sendmode']){
      case 1:
             $data['mobile'] //need to validate
             $data['firstname']   //need to validate
             $data['lastname']  //need to validate

             if($validate == TRUE){
                 //save data
             }
    //etc

   }
}
```

So I want all my validation done in my model, but first, I need to validate 3 fields, if thats true I need to continue, then if sendmode is 1, I need to validate other fields, as these fields will not exist if sendmode is 2 or 4 etc

Comment: Can you publish some code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you pass that json (?) data to a model method. Inside your model have a method that switches the validation rules based on the type.

```
// Controller
$this->Model->validateApiCall($this->request->input('json_decode', TRUE));

// Model
public function setValidationRules($type = 'someDefault') {
    switch($type){
        case SendMode::GROUP_FIELDS:
        $this->validate = array(/* your rules for that type here */);
        // ...

}

public function validateApiCall($data) {
    $this->setValidationRules($data['type']);
    // return or do something else with the data depending on it if its validated or not
    return $this->validate($data);
}
```

Oh, and if you really want to use integers for the types I would recommend to use constants like SendMode::GROUP_FIELDS. I usually create a tableless model for that. Constants are a lot better because if you do a typo it brings up a syntax error and while using plain integers nobody never ever is going to remember what the meaning of a random 3 or 4 or 1 is.

Comment: Thank you @burzum, Makes 100% sense, thank you for your response!